# Not getting updates as per Selected date in view contains Datagrid binded with Generic List?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

I have used tab control for view my usercontrols..
in 1st usercontrol
I have used datagrid to diplay Record and for Binding I have used generic List.
When want to change this List as per selected date then that collection is changed in database and in viewmodel also as List's  set propery get executes but in view when i selected new tab and then go back to prevois tab at that time List's get property executes & then  i am able get view as per selected date.

My main view and which contain 1st usercontrol as 1st tab item is given below:

[image]

Xaml code for above view is given below:

```
            <DataGrid
                Background="Transparent"
                CanUserAddRows="True"
                CanUserReorderColumns="False"

                ItemsSource="{Binding Model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Jama,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                HeadersVisibility="Column">
            </DataGrid>
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" >
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" >
                    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"  Width="75" Content="{Binding SumOfWeightJama,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Bold"  FontSize="16" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <DataGrid 
                Background="Transparent"
                CanUserAddRows="True"
                CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                ItemsSource="{Binding  Model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Udhar,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                HeadersVisibility="Column">
            </DataGrid>
            <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <Label Width="75" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"  Content="{Binding SumOfWeightUdhar,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Bold"  FontSize="16"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
```

And View Model for above View is given below:

```
private DateTime _FilterDate ;
public DateTime FilterDate
{
    get
    {
         return _FilterDate;
    }
    set
    {
        _FilterDate = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FilterDate");
        Model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Jama = (ViewModel.AllDataCollactions.AllTransactionsDetails.Where(s => s.TransactionDate.Equals(FilterDate) && s.IsJama).OrderBy(s => s.TransactionsID)).ToList();
        Model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Udhar = (ViewModel.AllDataCollactions.AllTransactionsDetails.Where(s => s.TransactionDate.Equals(FilterDate) && !s.IsJama).OrderBy(s => s.TransactionsID)).ToList();

    }
}
public List<Model_TransactionsDetails> Model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Jama
{
    get
    {
        return model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Jama;
    }
    set
    {
        model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Jama = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Jama");
    }
}
public List<Model_TransactionsDetails> Model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Udhar
{
    get
    {
        return model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Udhar;
    }
     set
    {
        model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Udhar = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Udhar");
    }
}
public ViewModel_MasterBook()
{
    FilterDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Date;
    InsertCommand = new RelayCommand(AddExecute, CanAdd);
}
```

Can any one help me How can i get view as per selected date immediately..

Comment: hey, i have another issue same as it but this time my collection is not getting changed as my expander's IsExpaned property changed. in my expander i have one observable collection which is not updated. but when i move to anther tab and go back to previous tab then observable collection getting updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually it should work i cant see an error. but when i use some kind of Lists in my WPF projects i use observablecollection with clear, add, delete.

but first i would change the binding

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Jama,Mode=OneWay}"
```

because Mode=TwoWay makes no sense, you never set the itemssource from your datagrid to the viewmodel.

second i would change to ObservableCollection

```
public ObservableCollection<Model_TransactionsDetails> Model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Jama
{
   get; private set;
}
```

with private setter because just initialize once.

//ctor

```
this.Model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Jama = new ObservableCollection<Model_TransactionsDetails>();
```

and then in your FilterDate setter fill the collection

```
this.Model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Jama.Clear();
var newdata = (ViewModel.AllDataCollactions.AllTransactionsDetails.Where(s => s.TransactionDate.Equals(FilterDate) && s.IsJama).OrderBy(s => s.TransactionsID)).ToList();
this.Model_Transactions_TransactionsDetails_Jama.AddRange(newdata);//AddRange is simply an extension method i wrote, you can simply use foreach and .Add()
```

Comment: i have same problem in datagrid Binding when i used expander in datagrid.My collection is not getting changed as my expander's IsExpaned property changed. in my expander i have one observable collection which is not updated. but when i move to anther tab and go back to previous tab then observable collection getting updated...@blindmeis